# SSH connection to a controlled network

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I have a cluster connected to the internet via our organization network. I usually connect from our internal network using ssh and do whatever I want to do. No problem there. The problem is when I want to connect to the computer from an outside network.

For the final public IP of the network, only the 80 and 8192 port is open. Also, I do have any jurisdiction over the network, so I can not change a thing. Is there any way to connect to that pc without changing the intermediary network.

Thank.

Comment: First two question to ask are: 1) Is this intentionally closed? 2) If not is everything using a normal IP or a kludge like RFC1918?   If 2 and not 1 ask for VPN access.

Answer (score 0):

As a former sysadmin/security guy... I cannot begin to describe how much this question makes me cringe.  SSH is disabled from the WAN for a reason... and it is quite possible that your company has a policy for doing this.  "Working around" this might get you fired, or possibly sued if something happens (even if you or what you did weren't the cause).

That being said, you can setup a reverse ssh tunnel on each of the servers to some sort of "meeting-point" box (something on your network at home?)  that would allow you to ssh into it to connect to those servers.  Typically outbound connections are not blocked... but if your network/security guy/sysadmin is doing his job, he will notice a bunch outbound connections to the same IP that lasts indefinitely.